# Binary operation ab+a defined on Q. Is it a group?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, binary-operations

A binary operation ∗ is defined on Q such that a∗b=ab+a. Is it a group?
I think that it's associative and the identity element is 0, but what about the inverse element?
 Am I right to think that for all a it's -1?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not a group; there is a right identity, which is $0$:
$$a*0 = a0 + a = a$$
and every element has a right inverse, which is $-1$ for all $a$
$$a*(-1) = a(-1)+a = 0$$
but the fact that the same element works as a right inverse for *everyone* already tells you this cannot possibly be a group (if $x^{-1}=y^{-1}$ in a group, then $x=y$).

In fact, the operation is not associative, since for example:
$$(3*2)*1 = (6+3)+9 = 18$$
but $$3*(2*1) = 3(2+2)+3 = 15$$
(among many other possibilities).

Moreover, the right identity is not a left identity, since $0*a = 0a+0 = 0$, which will not equal $a$ for all $a\neq 0$; and if you are given $a$, then $x*a = 0$ requires $0=xa+x = x(a+1)$, so only $a=-1$ has a left inverse.

So this is a magma with a right identity and right inverses, but not group.

Answer (score 3):

The binary operation is not associative. 
$a*(b*c)=a*(bc+b)=a(bc+b)+a=abc+ab+a\\
(a*b)*c=(ab+a)*c=(ab+a)c+(ab+a)=abc+ac+ab+a\\$ 
which need not be equal in general.
For example, take $a=b=c=1$ then $a*(b*c)=3$ and $(a*b)*c=4$.

Comment: Oh my, thank you! I had this whole thing so wrong. So when I get to, for example a*(bc+b) I, once again, have to do the operation with a*b=ab+a in mind, that's where you get a(bc+b) + another a from?

Comment: I'm not sure still where from (ab+a)*c we get (ab+a)c+(ab+b). Where does that (ab+b) come from? Or was that a typo and it's supposed to be (ab+a)?

Comment: That was a typo. The thing is that you verify the non-associativity of this binary operation.

Comment: “Which need not be equal in general”... okay, then show an explicit example of it not being equal. Sometimes things don’t look equal but actually are.

Comment: Take a, b and c to be 1.

Comment: Not to mention: the difference between them is $ac$.  They will be equal if and only if $ac=0$ if and only if $a=0$ or $c=0$.  I really do *not* think an explicit example was nesc.

Answer (score 3):

It is not a group, since$$a\ast a=a\iff a^2+a=a\iff a=0.$$So, only $0$ can be the identity element. But $0*1=0\ne1$. So, $(\Bbb Q,\ast)$ has no identity element.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you're saying with that a*a part:( I know when it comes to identity element a*e=e*a=a , so I'm thinking about a*e= ae+a, that's where i get that the identity element is 0.

Comment: If $(G,*)$ is a group, then the equation $g*g=g$ has one and only one solution in $G$, which is the identity element $e$ of $G$. In your case, I proved that that equation has indeed one and only one solution (it is $0$) but then I proved that that solution is *not* an identity element. So, $(\Bbb Q,\ast)$ has no identity element.

Comment: So am I not supposed to use the fact that a*b= ab+a (so a*0+a=a) anymore and just use a*b (a*0=0) , like you did?

Comment: Another way of demonstrating there is no identity is: $a * e = a \leadsto a e + a = a \leadsto a e = 0 \leadsto e = 0$ but plugging $e = 0$ into the other way round: $e * a = 0 a + 0 = 0$ so $a * 0 \ne 0 * a$ and so $0$ cannot be the identity after all.

Comment: But I *did* use that fact! Since $a\ast b=ab+a$, the equation $a\ast a=a$ becomes $a^2+a=a$.

Comment: Oh wait, the point is that you flip the numbers? Instead of 1*0 it's 0*1 ?

Comment: No, I did not flip any numbers. All I did was this: if $0$ was indeed the identity element, then we would have $0\ast q=q$ for every $q\in\Bbb Q$. But we don't have that, since $0\ast1=0\ne1$.

Comment: Sorry, I think I used the wrong word. But what I meant that if it works for q*0, like q*0= q*0+q=q , it has to work for 0*q too, and it doesn't because 0*q+0=0? Thank you for your patience.

Comment: No, it does *not* have to work for $0\ast q$ too, since your binary operation is not commutative.

Comment: well, the rule for the identity/neutral element is that there exists an element e in the group G, such that for all a: ae=ea=a, or so I thought, at least that's what I have in my ex.book. Also, when you say 0*1=0, do you use that 0*1=0*1+0. Or is that not relevant anymore?

Comment: What I used was the fact that $0\ast1=0\times1+0$.

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't look associative to me and $a*(b*c) = a*(bc +b)= abc + ab + a$ and $(a*b)*c = (ab + a)*c= (ab+a)c + (ab+a)  =abc + ac +ab +a$ which are of course not always equal.

To find an identity we must find an $x$ so that 1) $a*x=ax + a= a$ always and 2)$x*a= x*a +x = a$ always.

The so solution to 1) is $ax = 0$ so $x = 0$ for all $a$.  But the solution to 2) is $x(a+1)=a$ and if $a\ne 1$ then $x = \frac a{a+1}$ which is not a consistent value for every $a$.  So there is a right-identity but not an identity.

To find a right inverse to the right identity (There's no *point* in finding a left inverse to a right identity because we could never use that to solve anything--- although as $*$ isn't associative there's not point in finding an inverse at all because we can only use inverses to solve things when $*$ is associative) we must solve $a*x = ax + a=0$ so $x=-1$.  Which is interesting be we can use it to solve $ay = c$ because although $(ay)*-1 = c*(-1)$ is true and $a(y*-1)= a*0 = a$ is true and is *not* true that $(ay)*-1= a(y*-1)$, and also $c*(-1) = 0$ so this will never solve anything.

So no, it isn't a group.

Oh, what the heck to find a left inverse to the right identity.... $x*a =0$ means $xa+x=0$ and $x(a+1)=0$ so $x=0$.

Comment: $a\neq 1$ should be $a\neq -1$ in the third paragraph.